# How can we parse the result fetched from odoo using the odoo_api in flutter?

Tags: flutter, odoo

I used the odoo_api v1.0.2 package in order to fetch all the records from odoo.

```
final domain = [
          ["sale_ok", "!=", false]
        ];
        var fields = ["name", "list_price"];
        client
            .searchRead("product.template", domain, fields)
            .then((OdooResponse result) {
          if (!result.hasError()) {
            print("Succesful");
            final data = result.getResult();
            print("Total: ${data['length']}");
            final records = ("${data["records"]}");
            print(records);
          } else {
            print(result.getError());
          }
        });
```

I want to take individual record from the product list in odoo and display it as products in my flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model like:

```
class ItemModel {
  final int id;
  final String type;
  final int time;
  final String text;
  final bool dead;

  ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : id = parsedJson['id'],
        type = parsedJson['type'],
        time = parsedJson['time'],
        text = parsedJson['text'],
        dead = parsedJson['dead'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      "id": id,
      "type": type,
      "time": time,
      "text": text,
      "dead": dead,
    };
  }
}
```

And use like ->

```
final item = ItemModel.fromJson(parsedJson);
```

Comment: when i print the result i get from odoo_api, the result isn't in a valid json format.
[{name: Apple In-Ear Headphones, id: 16, list_price: 79.0}, {name: Datacard, id: 5, list_price: 40.0}, {name: Motherboard I9P57, id: 26, list_price: 1950.0}, {name: Apple Wireless Keyboard, id: 18, list_price: 47.0}]

Comment: because your result is a List of Map<String, dynamic>. You should map your result and add to another list one by one as model.

Comment: also before mapping you should decode your record like -> Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson = json.decode(record);

Comment: E/flutter (14446): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
I'm getting this error.